# Java Swing how to let the JFrame gain focus

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing a java swing application. I wish to achieve such result: press shortcut to let the app window show up. press shortcut again or click otherwhere to let the app hide.

I use jkeymaster to register to listen the event of global shortcut and it works well.
But when the user focus on some other window, like chrome, office... the focus window will be other application. Then if the user use the shortcut. My app windows will still show up but cannot gain focus. Could anyone help me to solve it. Here's my code snippet.

```
    Provider provider = Provider.getCurrentProvider(true);
    // bind shortcut
    provider.register(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()), x -> {
        homePage.setVisible(!homePage.isVisible());
        if(homePage.isVisible()){
            // TODO: 2020/10/1 request focus here
            homePage.requestFocusInWindow();
            homePage.requestFocus();

            KeyboardFocusManager focusManager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
            focusManager.clearGlobalFocusOwner();

            log.info("hasFocus？ " + homePage.hasFocus());
            log.info("isActive？ " + homePage.isActive());
        }
    });
```

What I have tried:

1. requestFocus and requestFocusInWindow, doesn't work
2. I read the source code of requestFocus. It says

```
     * This method cannot be used to set the focus owner to no Component at
     * all. Use <code>KeyboardFocusManager.clearGlobalFocusOwner()</code>
     * instead.
```

So I tried focusManager.clearGlobalFocusOwner() but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe `grabFocus()` will work?

Comment: @camickr thank you for advice but JFrame dosent have grabFocus method. I tried homePage.getRootPane().grabFocus() but still dosent work.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when you want to gain focus in a parent container (such as `JPanel`, `JFrame`, etc) you request the focus by calling `requestFocusInWindow()` method into one of its children.

I suggest you, to not asking for focus in the `JFrame`. Call `requestFocusInWindow()` in one of its components.

Now in terms of UX, I would give the focus back to last component that was focused. In order to get the focused component of a `JFrame` we call `jframe.getFocusOwner()`. However, if the `JFrame` is in state `MINIMIZED` or is in background, since it does not have focus, `getFocusOwner` returns `null`.

So, in order to find the last component that was focused before calling your global key listener, you can register a global AWT listener for focus events as well:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(e -> {
    if (e.getID() == FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST) {
        if (e.getSource() instanceof Component) {
            lastFocusedComponent = (Component) e.getSource();
        }
    }
}, FocusEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK);
```

Listener will be fired every time the focus changes. So you get the actual last component with focus safely, eliminating the chance to be `null` since it is the one that fires the event.

All you have to do after it, is to call `requestFocusInWindow` to it:

```
provider.register(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, 0), e -> {
    frame.setVisible(!frame.isVisible());
    if (frame.isVisible())
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(lastFocusedComponent::requestFocusInWindow);
});
```

A full example that works (you can confirm your self that the focus is restored):

```
public class FocusExample {
    private static Component lastFocusedComponent;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JTextField leftField = new JTextField(10);
            JTextField rightField = new JTextField(10);

            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.add(leftField);
            frame.add(rightField);

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(e -> {
                if (e.getID() == FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST) {
                    if (e.getSource() instanceof Component) {
                        lastFocusedComponent = (Component) e.getSource();
                    }
                }
            }, FocusEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK);

            Provider provider = Provider.getCurrentProvider(true);

            provider.register(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, 0), e -> {
                frame.setVisible(!frame.isVisible());
                if (frame.isVisible())
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(lastFocusedComponent::requestFocusInWindow);
            });

            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It does reach the result you said actually, but it's not what I want. I wish the JFrame could grab focus because another need is 'JFrame should auto hide when JFrame lost focus'. If JFrame can not get focus when it shows up, I can not monitor it's focuslost event. I think the implementation is different on different platform. Could you please give me some further advice?